# Lipschitz normally embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Given $(X,d_i)$ a smooth compact connected submanifold with intrinsic distance $d_i$ embedded in $R^d$. Is it true that:
$d_i(x,x')\leq K\Vert x-x' \Vert $ for some $K>0$?
If that is the case, how can $K$ be related to the geometry of $X$?